# Knex.js count distinct column with alias

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I want to generate this SQL code:

```
Select count(distinct user_id) as ui
from posts
```

I tried this snippet but it did not work:

```
knex('posts').countDistinct('user_id').as('ui');
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that both count() and countDistinct can parse raw queries like this:

```
knex('posts').countDistinct('user_id as ui') ;

knex('posts').count('user_id as ui') ;
```

Comment: how to make sure that the value output from .count() is always integer. not null , undefined or string